# Knockout.js, foreach and afterRender

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Is there a way for fiering an event after the last value in an obervable array have been rendered?
I have the following code:

```
<table class="resultListTable">
<thead class="header">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: resultList, afterRender: afterRender}">
    <tr class="resultList" data-bind="attr: {id: Rno}">
        <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Customer"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Status"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>

    function afterRender() {

        $(".resultList").on("click", function (e) {
            if(!exceptionRedirected){
                var url = '~/Home/Detail/' +  $(e.target).closest("tr").attr("id");
                window.location.href = url;
            }
        });
    }

function viewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.resultList = ko.observableArray([]);
}

function CustStatus(data) {
     var self = this;   
     self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id || '');
     self.Rno = ko.observable(data.Rno || '');
     self.Customer = ko.observable(data.Id || '');
     self.Status = ko.observable(data.Id || '');
}

    var vm = new CustStatus();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    /* I get the data from a ajax call somewhere else in the code */

</script>
```

The `afterRender` function is executed for every line of data.
How can I execute this only at the end of the data array?

Comment: What about if you update the array but only change elements in the middle. Does it not only re-render the elements that have changed? It might be better as a custom binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the click knockout binding.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: resultList}">
    <tr class="resultList" data-bind="attr: {id: Rno}, click: $root.detailClick">
        <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Customer"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Status"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

With the function detailClick in the viewModel:

```
function viewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.resultList = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.detailClick = function(custStatus) {
         var url = '~/Home/Detail/' + custStatus.Rno();
         window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but for some reason I don't get that to fire. I guess that click event will end up on the **tr** element?

Comment: correction: the function detailClick should be inside the viewmodel. Editing now

Comment: I got this to work: click: detailClick
(removed the $root.)

Thank you Leszek